# Filtro y Asignación en R

Tags: r

Tengo la siguiente situación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, por registro único en identificación poner la menor Fecha de Ingreso y la mayor Fecha de Retiro.

Agradezco su enorme ayuda.. estoy desesperado

Feliz Tarde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con R base, creo que la mejor forma es:

```
merge(
    aggregate( fecha_ingreso ~ identificacion, data = df, min),
    aggregate( fecha_retiro ~ identificacion, data = df, max), 
    all.x = TRUE,
    all.y = TRUE,
    by = "identificacion"
)
```

- Usamos `aggregate()` para agrupar por `identificacion` y aplicar `min()` y `max()` a `fecha_ingreso` y `fecha_retiro` resepctivamente
- Luego con `merge()` juntamos las dos salidas por `identificacion`

Sino, usando `dplyr` de `tidyverse`

```
df %>% 
    group_by(identificacion) %>% 
    summarize(fecha_ingreso = min(fecha_ingreso, na.rm = TRUE),
              fecha_retiro = max(fecha_retiro, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Mucho mas entendible, la única contra es un `warning` producto de los valores `NA` que podemos ignorar.

Comment: Buenas Tardes, para agradecer la ayuda , me resirvió la solución número 1